# Burnside ring and zeroth G-equivariant stem for finite G

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, equivariant-homotopy, reference-request

Let $G$ be a finite group. The theorem that the Burnside ring $A(G)$ is isomorphic to the zeroth stable stem $\pi^{G}_0(S)$ is usually said to originate from Segal. I search for a reference of a proof this theorem, which is not obscured by tom Diecks generalisation to compact Lie groups. Who knows a good reference? I can not even find the right paper of Segal. Where did the original proof appear?

Answer (score 4):

This is from Segal's paper

Equivariant stable homotopy theory. Actes du Congrès International des Mathématiciens (Nice, 1970), Tome 2, pp. 59--63. Gauthier-Villars, Paris, 1971.

MR0423340 (54 #11319)

where he states that the equivariant stable cohomotopy of $S$ is $\pi_G^{-\ast}(S)=\bigoplus_K\pi_{\ast}^s(B(N_G(K)/K)^+)$. In particular, $\pi_G^0(S)$ is the Burnside ring.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I got a copy from the library. Do you know of any alternative account, written may be in a more teaching style?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed this. The only other reference I know for a proof of this is Lewis-May-McClure from LMN 1213, Chapter V, &sect; 2. (This is available for download from May's ["old books page"](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/BOOKSMaster.html) if you're interested.) Though they treat the general case, you may find it easy to extract those portions of the discussion that are relevant for your purposes.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a conceptual answer, which can be filled in to give a proof.  First, go back to the non-equivariant setting: why is $\pi_0(S) = \lim \pi_N(S^N) \cong {\mathbb Z}$?  because one can use transversality arguments (originally due to Pontryagin) to show that group is the same as the cobordism group of ``oriented'' zero-dimensional manifolds, which is then obviously the integers.  Similarly, the cobordism of oriented zero-dimensional $G$-manifolds is isomorphic to the Burnside ring, so the result you seek follows once you can establish some transversality for maps $S^V \to S^V$.  (These transversality results are notoriously complicated and not always valid in the equivariant setting, but this one doesn't present much trouble).